# Condition on more than one random variables or sigma-algebra

Tags: probability, measure-theory, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation

The first question is:
Assume we have four random variables $A,B,C,D$, each one is a positive random variable with support $\text{supp}X$ but they are not independent. Given that if $A,B$ are given, the random variable $C$ is drawn from its marginal distribution $P_C$. Furthermore, given that $D$ and $C$ are not independent and $D$ is also not independent with both $A$ and $B$. I don't know whether $C$ and $D$ are conditionally independent given $A,B$ or not.

Hence, the question is: whether the following statement is true or not
$$E[C\vert A,B,D]=E_{P_C}[C|A,B]?$$

The second related question is: If we assume $A$ is $F$-measurable and $P_A(A=x|F)$ is a $pmf$ for all support $x\in\text{supp}P_A$ and $B$ is $G$-measurable where $F$ and $G$ are two sigma-algebra and $F\subset G$. Given that $A$ and $B$ are not independent. The question is: whether the following statement is true or not
$$P_A(A=x|F,B)=P_A(A=x|F)$$ where $x$ is in the support of the distribution $P_A$.

Comment: Do you know anything about $D$? As the question is posed now, it seems that $D=C$ is entirely possible.

Comment: @Dodezv Thank you for your comment. I think I have figured out my problem since $D$ and $C$ are not conditional independent given $A, B$.